# Finding the nearest array set

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, logic

I wanted to know what possible algorithm I could use to find which in the set of array below is nearest to **[0,0,0]**. I am thinking of giving points to each set by adding the values of each set, but the problem is the array index 1 **[0,2,1]** will have a sum of **3** which is equal to array index 3. The answer below should be index 3, or do you have better suggestion? thanks in advance.

```
$sets = [
    [4,5,6], // 0
    [0,2,1], // 1
    [1,3,0], // 2
    [1,1,1], // 3
    [0,1,3], // 4
    [5,4,3], // 5
]
```

Comment: How do you define `nearest` here? Based on what criteria / formula?

Comment: It was given that 1,1,1 is the nearest to 0,0,0, so what I am looking for is the formula to say that 1,1,1 is nearest to 0,0,0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, what you're basically describing corresponds to finding the distance to the origin for a point in 3D space, the formula for which is:

[image: formula]

Based on that, the point `[1, 1, 1]` is indeed closer to the origin than `[0, 2, 1]`:

[image: formula-1]

[image: formula-2]

In PHP, you could calculate the distances as follows:

```
$sets = [[4,5,6], [0,2,1], [1,3,0], [1,1,1], [0,1,3], [5,4,3]];

$distances = array_map(function ($i) {
    return sqrt($i[0]**2 + $i[1]**2 + $i[2]**2);
}, $sets);

print_r($distances);
```

Finding the closest point then becomes trivial.

Comment: Thanks man! are there other topics you think i need to read about 3 space?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do, I guess... I like [this book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781849960236).